# How could I do open a specific Fragment about NotificationMessage?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications

I have some Fragments(1,2,3,4,5), and I created a push message that display a NotificationMessage(NotificationManager) in notification bar. I want when "touch" in the NotificationMessage the specific Fragment is opened.

The problem is I don't know how can I do it, there's some way to send push with a parameter and after receive I get this parameter and open the specific Fragment ?

An example, in WhatsApp I have a contact, and when this contact send a message for me I touch the notification and does open my messages with this contact.

How could I do it ?

Below my SendNotification class, in this class I do open SplashView. The SplashView is a Activity but I want to open a Fragment, for example Fragment3

```
public class SendNotification {

    public SendNotification(Context context, String title, String tickerText, String message, String url) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent;

        Intent intentJogarComOponente = new Intent(context, SplashView.class);
        Bundle bd = new Bundle();
        bd.putString("title",title);
        bd.putString("description",message);
        bd.putString("url",url);
        intentJogarComOponente.putExtras(bd);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentJogarComOponente, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setTicker(tickerText)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        if(!PushControl.getIsVisible()){
            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
            mNotificationManager.notify(AndroidSystemUtil.randInt(), notification);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
intentJogarComOponente .putExtra("started_from","notification");

to the code that starts the intent from the notifications, and the same thing
to the other startActivity calls just change the value, then inside your 
activity

String startedFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra("started_from");
```

And check it in your activity if you are getting do your wished fragment replace transaction and start get your desired fragment.